# WordPress добавление в метаданные пост тайпа

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

Только осваиваю WordPress, есть кастомный пост тайп.

```
function setup_custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'thumbnail',
        'public'    => true,
        'label'     => __( 'Listing', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'listing'),
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'setup_custom_post_type' );
```

Хочу добавить поле в метаданные поста, в котором будет время добавления, но моя функция не работает.

```
function save_custom_post_tye(){
    add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date_cr', date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'save_custom_post_tye', 10, 3);
```

Что нужно поменять/добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `get_the_ID()` работает только в главном цикле WordPress. Вам нужно использовать аргументы, которые передаются в хук.

```
/**
 * Save custom post meta at creation.
 *
 * @param int     $post_id Post ID.
 * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
 * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
 */
function save_custom_post_type( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'date_cr', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'save_custom_post_type', 10, 3 );
```